# Unable to add key and bool value into nested list

Tags: flutter, dart

**Example Code (Not working):**

```
void main() {
  List json = [
    {
      "sku": "SKU0001",
      "uids": [
        {
          "uid": "U001"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  var result = json.map( (item) {
    item['no_desc'] = true; // able to add the key and bool value
    item['uids'] = item['uids'].map( (uid) {
      uid['is_scanned'] = true; // failed to add, but able to accept string value only. 
      return uid;
    }).toList();
    return item;
  }).toList();
  
  print(result);
}
```

return error ***'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'***

**Expected Result**

```
[
  {
   sku: SKU0001, 
   no_desc: true,
   uids: [
    {
       uid: U001, 
       is_scanned: true // must be boolean
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

It work when i try in `String` value.

```
 uid['is_scanned'] = 'true';
```

How can I add bool value into the nested list?

If I am writing in javascript way,
it should be able to add the key into nested array ( list ).

But why in dart lang, it prompt me error?
Can someone expert in dart lang willing to explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be fixed by creating a new `Map` instance in the inner `.map` method with the `Map.from` constructor.

```dart
item['uids'] = item['uids'].map( (uid) {
  uid['is_scanned'] = true; // failed to add, but able to accept string value only. 
  return uid;
}).toList();
```

should be changed to:

```dart
item['uids'] = item['uids'].map( (uid) {
  Map<String, dynamic> toReturn = Map.from(uid);
  toReturn['is_scanned'] = true;
  return toReturn;
}).toList();
```

I believe this issue is due to dart implicitly declaring the inner `uids` maps as `Map<String, String>` so creating a new instance changes this and allows you to assign any value to the keys of the `Map`.

Full working sample:

```dart
void main() {
  List json = [
    {
      "sku": "SKU0001",
      "uids": [
        {
          "uid": "U001"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  var result = json.map( (item) {
    item['no_desc'] = true;
    item['uids'] = item['uids'].map( (uid) {
      Map<String, dynamic> toReturn = Map.from(uid);
      toReturn['is_scanned'] = true;
      return toReturn;
    }).toList();
    return item;
  }).toList();
  
  print(result);
}
```